# Java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/common/base/FinalizableReference.class

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

Why am getting this error it will not occurred when I sync the Gradle but when I'm running the project I am getting this error .

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForRelease'. > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/common/base/FinalizableReference.class

I don't know which dependency cause this error, My dependencies are .

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:percent:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.19.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.3.4'
    compile 'io.nlopez.smartlocation:library:3.3.1'
    compile 'com.appeaser.sublimenavigationviewlibrary:sublimenavigationviewlibrary:0.0.1'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.daimajia.slider:library:1.1.5@aar'
    compile 'com.afollestad:sectioned-recyclerview:0.4.1'
    compile 'com.github.medyo:fancybuttons:1.8.3'
    compile 'com.basgeekball:awesome-validation:2.0'
    compile 'com.github.michaelye.easydialog:easydialog:1.4'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**Edit**

I figured it out play service dependencies causing this problem. when I'm using `10.2.6` instead of `11.0.0` app is working perfectly, I just change dependecies to

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.2.6'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.2.6'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.6'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:10.2.6'
```

but I want to use latest version of play-services `11.0.0` but it gives me the above problem. How to resolve this problem? Any help would be appriciated Thanks.

Comment: use `compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5+`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya still the same error

Comment: I think its a bug . You can raise that

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya problem solved by removing this line `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`. I think question should be closed?

Comment: No . You can add this as answer .

Comment: @AbhishekSingh, how could you say that removing apply plugin 'com.google.gms.google-services' will solve the issue

Comment: @Po10cio Use play Service Version `11.0.1` the we don't need to delete this line

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally problem is solved. Seems like its a bug google resolved this issue in updated version.

Use play Service Version `11.0.1`

In project level gradle use

`classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'`

Comment: I'm having the same issue, but if I delete the line `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` like you've suggested, the build no longer parses my `google-services.json` file, and so my api keys for Firebase messaging don't get added to R.string, and the build fails because I use those in several places. Any ideas for this?

Comment: There is no way your app will build, i am currently having the same issues since i upgraded to Firebase and play services 11.0.0, i think it is a bug

Comment: @Breeno Use play Service Version `11.0.1`

Comment: I think that will fix it if it ai available

Comment: @Abhishek Singh I can't seem to find Google Play Services v11.0.1, if I put it in my gradle file it says it can't locate it and won't build, and I see no mention of it on [Google website](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases). Are you on some sort of beta update channel? For time being I've reverted to 10.2.6 which works ok.

Comment: @Breeno check your link again.. It has first line written there `Google Play services updated 11.0.1 This release fixes an issue impacting apps using rxjava.`

Comment: @Abhishek Singh Thanks Abhishek, I see 11.0.1 is there now. It definitely wasn't there when I checked it at the time - it still read v11.0.0 as the latest release at that point. There was some warning text explaining there was a bug in v11.0.0 affecting RxJava users and suggesting a workaround by modifying the gradle file. As if to prove it, my comment was upvoted twice as well. Thanks, all sorted now.

Comment: @Breeno but also I'm using `11.0.1` before your comment. Also I'm not using any beta channel. I don't know how this happen my android studio gives me suggestion to use `11.0.1`. Anyway problem is solved now.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, this issue happens because of including different version of play-services (or some other libraries). Have a look at app dependencies using below:

**gradle app:dependencies**

or if you are using Gradle wrapper

**./gradlew app:dependencies**

There might be some other third party library that is using an older version of library. If that is the case, exclude the older library from the third party library and include the latest one.

You can do something like this:

```
compile ('com.thirdpartylib.android:library-sdk:8.3.0') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-gcm'
        compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:26.0.0'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.2.0'
    }
```

This should resolve any duplicate entry, the main reason for the issue

Comment: nope bro it is issue in `11.0.0` which is fixed in later versions