# Failed to resolve: com.android.support:customtabs:[26.0.0,26.1.0]

Tags: android, android-studio, android-support-library

I have these two errors:

**Failed to resolve: com.android.support:custom tabs:[26.0.0,26.1.0]**

**Failed to resolve: com.android.support:support-v4:[26.0.0,26.1.0]**

[image: Screenshot: of Error]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through [the welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Answer (score 32):

Now Android support package disturbs over network(starts from 25.4), so your project's build.gradle file should include that:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Also you can add `google()` instead of `maven{url "..."}`:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}
```

Comment: that error is resolved but a new error

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/internal/zzed.class

Comment: @PrincePandey try clean/rebuild project

Comment: @PrincePandey also, check that you don't have dublicate libraries in build.gradle

Comment: @PrincePandey and, if error still appears, try that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44541963/7996129

Comment: i have same error for my project. Can you find any solution ?

Comment: @mrtcnkryln did you add Google maven repo in project's gradle file?

Comment: This just came out of no where for me too, did you find a solution?

Comment: Try to disable offline work in Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build tools -> Gradle