# Failed resolving dependencies due to OneSignal

Tags: android, gradle, onesignal

I found the following question: [Failed to resolve: com.android.support:customtabs:[26.0.0,26.1.0]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45649426/failed-to-resolve-com-android-supportcustomtabs26-0-0-26-1-0)
People marked it as duplicate (which is wrong ! see next sentence) or wrote something about Maven or cleaning project etc.

I have exactly the same problem for two days (failed to resolve customtabs and support-v4) and I did not change anything in my project which has been previously working. So I started looking for possible solutions and I found the problem - it is the OneSignal dependency - when I remove it, everything works fine. But I have already implemented notifications in my app - and don't know what to do now. I tried to compile the newest one (mentioned on OneSignal page)

```
compile 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:[3.6.0,3.99.99)'
```

But the result is same. Can anyone help?

UPDATE:

The problem can be very easy reproduced - please create a simple project and add this dependency mentioned below (it is from official OneSignal website https://documentation.onesignal.com/v3.0/docs/android-sdk-setup):

```
 compile 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:[3.6.0, 3.99.99]'
```

UPDATE 2:

These are my dependencies:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:1.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
compile 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:[3.6.0, 3.99.99]'
```

Adding

```
maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
```

to the build.gradle solved the problem with OneSignal, but now I have a problem with Firebase:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method zzdD(Ljava/lang/String;)Z in class Lcom/google/android/gms/common/util/zzv; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.common.util.zzv'
```

Comment: post both gradle files root and app

Answer (score 2):

The error happens because you have some conflicted library in your dependency.

As in the [documentation](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/android-sdk-setup), it says:

> Automatic Dependencies
>   OneSignal automatically adds the following dependencies;
>
> - com.google.android.gms - Version 11
> - com.android.support - Version 26
>
> Please makes sure your project matches these versions if you run into
>   a mismatch version error.
>
> For more details see the [All gms/firesbase libraries must use the
>   exact same version specification](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/troubleshooting-android#section-error-all-gms-firesbase-libraries-must-use-the-exact-same-version-specification) section.

So, you need to remove or use the same dependencies in your project, something like this:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.+'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.+'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.+'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:1.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.+'
compile 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:[3.6.0, 3.99.99]'
```

Comment: he is already using the same versions of firebase dependencies

Comment: Can I add it with another version of the support library, 26.0.0-alpha1 for example ?

Comment: I think you can, but you need to exclude the support library in. Something like this `compile ('com.onesignal:OneSignal:[3.6.0, 3.99.99]') {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat-v7'
}`

Answer (score 1):

Remove 'f' from dependency. also, use [ brackets instead of ). its a typo.

```
    dependencies {
    compile 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:[3.6.0, 3.99.99]'
}
```

and this code in your root gradle file

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this was written accidentally in the question, thank you for posting, now I corrected it. Dependency is correct in the project so your answer doesnt help.

Comment: see its typo compile 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:[3.6.0,3.99.99f99)'

Comment: use [ ] , not [ )

Comment: ? I said this was only accedintally put character here in the question! the dependency in project is exactly as you wrote it

Comment: No this has nothing with it. See official documentation - there must be [ at the beginning and ) at the end

Comment: post your gradle files

Comment: did you try to put this dependency in a project ? see my update

Comment: doing that only wait

Comment: gott same problem but resolved after adding . allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}. in root gardle