# duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/internal/zzfj.class

Tags: java, android

Please help me: Here is Screenshot of Error:

[image]

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/internal/zzfj.class][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r8qsR.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r8qsR.png)

Gradle File: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxZ4QxQmqfMHV05oVFc0QmxuTlU

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'


    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
        applicationId "aa.bb"
        manifestPlaceholders = [onesignal_app_id               : "xxx",
                                // Project number pulled from dashboard, local value is ignored.
                                onesignal_google_project_number: "REMOTE"]

        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url "https://jitpack.io"
    }
    maven {
        url "https://mint.splunk.com/gradle/"
    }

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    compile project(':ResideMenu')




    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:[3.5.3,4.0.0)'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.2'
    compile 'org.apmem.tools:layouts:1.10@aar'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'com.splunk.mint:mint:5.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.github.siyamed:android-shape-imageview:0.9.+@aar'
    compile 'com.github.justzak:dilatingdotsprogressbar:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.kaopiz:kprogresshud:1.1.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: post your gradle file..

Comment: Anything related to `com.google.android.gms` (Play Services) in the `libs/` directory in your project?

Comment: The error is happening because `com.onesignal` dependencies. Please look at the same question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45673427/failed-resolving-dependencies-due-to-onesignal/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed resolving dependencies due to OneSignal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45673427/failed-resolving-dependencies-due-to-onesignal)

Comment: @Thomas it was not the same problem, my problem is still the same

Comment: @AalapPatel I tried that code but it didn't work

Comment: Please post the exception stacktrace as text, not as a screenshot