# WebView App APK failed: mobile:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug

Tags: android, webview, duplicates, build.gradle

I'm building a WebView native app, provided by [robotemplates](https://codecanyon.net/item/universal-android-webview-app/8431507). I encountered this build failure message when I try to build the APK:

Error:Execution failed for task ':mobile:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/internal/zzfj.class

If anyone has a solution to the duplicate, please help.

Here's my build.gradle, happy to provide other information if needed:

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
}

dependencies
{
    compile "com.android.support:support-compat:25.1.1"
    compile "com.android.support:support-core-utils:25.1.1"
    compile "com.android.support:support-core-ui:25.1.1"
    compile "com.android.support:support-fragment:25.1.1"
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.1"
    compile "com.android.support:design:25.1.1"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:10.0.1"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:10.0.1"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.0.1"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.0.1"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.0.1"
    compile "com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.4.3@aar"
    compile (name:"config", ext:"aar")
    compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    compile 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:[3.6.2, 3.99.99]'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'


}
...
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Here's my other build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
        }
    }
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.14.1'
}
```

(I'm a newbie, please bear with me as I'm figuring out multiple errors)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed resolving dependencies due to OneSignal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45673427/failed-resolving-dependencies-due-to-onesignal)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to compile two OneSignal libraries

```
compile "com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.4.3@aar"
compile 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:[3.6.2, 3.99.99]’
```

try to remove one.