# When I try to generate app, following error produce

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

While trying to generate android app, i am getting following error.So kindly let me know what was wrong with my gradle file or some where else.

```
 Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForRelease'.
```

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/iid/zzc.class

**Build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26'

    defaultConfig {

        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 19

        multiDexEnabled true

        renderscriptTargetApi 19
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true

        manifestPlaceholders = [appPackageName: "${applicationId}"]
    }
    dexOptions {
        jumboMode true
    }


    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        pickFirst 'AndroidManifest.xml'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.0.0' 
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.0' 

    compile 'com.adobe.creativesdk.foundation:auth:0.9.1251'
    compile 'com.adobe.creativesdk:image:4.8.4'
    compile 'com.localytics.android:library:3.8.0'

}
```

Detailed Stacktrace As Below

_releaseCompile - ## Internal use, do not manually configure ##

```
+--- com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1
+--- com.larswerkman:HoloColorPicker:1.5
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0
|    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.2.0
|    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.0
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.2.0
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.2.0
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-media-compat:25.2.0
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.2.0
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.2.0 (*)
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:25.2.0
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.2.0
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.2.0 (*)
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:25.2.0
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.2.0
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.2.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-fragment:25.2.0
|    |         +--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.2.0 (*)
|    |         +--- com.android.support:support-media-compat:25.2.0 (*)
|    |         +--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:25.2.0 (*)
|    |         \--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:25.2.0 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:25.2.0
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.2.0
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.2.0 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:25.2.0
|         \--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:25.2.0 (*)
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.0.1
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite:[11.0.1] -> 11.0.1
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[11.0.1] -> 11.0.1
|    |         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:[11.0.1] -> 11.0.1
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[11.0.1] -> 11.0.1 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:[11.0.1] -> 11.0.1
|    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[11.0.1] -> 11.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-clearcut:[11.0.1] -> 11.0.1
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:[11.0.1] -> 11.0.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[11.0.1] -> 11.0.1 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:[11.0.1] -> 11.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[11.0.1] -> 11.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-gass:[11.0.1] -> 11.0.1
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[11.0.1] -> 11.0.1 (*)
|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-safetynet:[11.0.1] -> 11.0.1
|         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:[11.0.1] -> 11.0.1 (*)
|         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[11.0.1] -> 11.0.1 (*)
|         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:[11.0.1] -> 11.0.1 (*)
+--- com.startapp:inapp-sdk:3.6.3
+--- com.alexzh:circleimageview:1.1.2
+--- com.amitshekhar.android:android-networking:1.0.0
|    +--- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.6.0
|    |    \--- com.squareup.okio:okio:1.11.0
|    \--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0
+--- cn.pedant.sweetalert:library:1.3
|    \--- com.pnikosis:materialish-progress:1.0
|         \--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0 -> 25.2.0 (*)
+--- com.appnext.sdk:native-ads:2.+ -> 2.0.6.462
|    \--- com.appnext.sdk:core:2.0.6.462
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.0.1 (*)
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.1
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:[11.0.1] -> 11.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[11.0.1] -> 11.0.1 (*)
|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:[11.0.1] -> 11.0.1 (*)
+--- com.edmodo:cropper:1.0.1
+--- com.adobe.creativesdk.foundation:auth:0.9.1251
|    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:25.0.1 -> 25.2.0 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1 -> 25.2.0 (*)
|    +--- commons-io:commons-io:2.4
|    +--- com.birbit:android-priority-jobqueue:2.0.0-beta2
|    |    +--- com.squareup.okio:okio:1.8.0 -> 1.11.0
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3 -> 25.2.0 (*)
|    \--- com.readystatesoftware.systembartint:systembartint:1.0.3
+--- com.adobe.creativesdk:image:4.8.4
|    +--- com.jakewharton.hugo:hugo-annotations:1.2.1
|    +--- com.adobe.creativesdk.foundation:auth:0.9.1251 (*)
|    +--- com.sothree.slidinguppanel:library:3.3.1
|    |    +--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0 -> 25.0.0
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.0.0 -> 25.2.0
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.0.0 -> 25.2.0 (*)
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:25.0.0 -> 25.2.0 (*)
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0 -> 25.2.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:23.4.0 -> 25.2.0
|    +--- it.sephiroth.android.library.targettooltip:target-tooltip-library:1.3.15
|    |    \--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1 -> 25.2.0 (*)
|    +--- it.sephiroth.android.library.picasso:picasso:2.5.2.4b
|    |    +--- com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.1.0
|    |    |    \--- com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.1.0
|    |    |         \--- com.squareup.okio:okio:1.0.1 -> 1.11.0
|    |    +--- com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.1.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.intellij:annotations:12.0
|    +--- it.sephiroth.android.exif:android-exif-extended:1.0.6
|    |    +--- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.3.2 -> 3.4
|    |    \--- commons-io:commons-io:2.4
|    +--- it.sephiroth.android.library.disklrumulticache:disklrumulticache:1.0.8
|    |    +--- commons-io:commons-io:2.4
|    |    \--- com.jakewharton:disklrucache:2.0.2
|    +--- it.sephiroth.android.library.viewrevealanimator:view-reveal-animator:1.1.4
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3 -> 25.2.0 (*)
|    +--- com.timehop.stickyheadersrecyclerview:library:0.4.3
|    |    \--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.0 -> 25.0.0 (*)
|    +--- io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.1
|    |    \--- io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.6 -> 1.2.2
|    +--- it.sephiroth:rxbroadcast:0.0.2
|    |    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0 -> 25.2.0 (*)
|    |    \--- io.reactivex:rxjava:1.0.14 -> 1.2.2
|    +--- com.trello:rxlifecycle-components:0.8.0
|    |    +--- com.trello:rxlifecycle-android:0.8.0
|    |    |    +--- com.trello:rxlifecycle:0.8.0
|    |    |    |    +--- io.reactivex:rxjava:1.2.0 -> 1.2.2
|    |    |    |    \--- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.1
|    |    |    \--- com.jakewharton.rxbinding:rxbinding:0.4.0
|    |    |         +--- io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.1.0 -> 1.2.1 (*)
|    |    |         +--- io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.0 -> 1.2.2
|    |    |         \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:23.1.0 -> 25.2.0
|    |    +--- io.reactivex:rxjava:1.2.0 -> 1.2.2
|    |    \--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0 -> 25.2.0 (*)
|    +--- com.trello:rxlifecycle:0.8.0 (*)
|    +--- com.jakewharton.rxbinding:rxbinding:0.4.0 (*)
|    +--- com.jakewharton.rxbinding:rxbinding-appcompat-v7:0.4.0
|    |    +--- com.jakewharton.rxbinding:rxbinding:0.4.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0 -> 25.2.0 (*)
|    +--- com.jakewharton.rxbinding:rxbinding-support-v4:0.4.0
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.0 -> 25.2.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.jakewharton.rxbinding:rxbinding:0.4.0 (*)
|    +--- io.reactivex:rxjava-async-util:0.21.0
|    |    \--- io.reactivex:rxjava:1.0.0-rc.3 -> 1.2.2
|    +--- com.getbase:floatingactionbutton:1.10.0
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:22.2.0 -> 25.2.0
|    +--- com.adobe.creativesdk:image-native:1.3.344
|    |    +--- com.jakewharton.hugo:hugo-annotations:1.2.1
|    |    +--- com.adobe.creativesdk.android.shared:android-shared:0.0.9
|    |    |    +--- com.jakewharton.hugo:hugo-annotations:1.2.1
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-v13:24.1.1
|    |    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1 -> 25.2.0 (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.infstory:proguard-annotations:1.0.2
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:24.1.1 -> 25.2.0
|    |    |    +--- commons-io:commons-io:2.4
|    |    |    +--- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1 -> 3.6.0 (*)
|    |    |    \--- io.reactivex:rxjava:1.2.0 -> 1.2.2
|    |    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1 -> 25.2.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.infstory:proguard-annotations:1.0.2
|    +--- de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.0.0
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.4.0
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:9.4.0 -> 11.0.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.4.0 -> 11.0.1 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-iid:9.4.0
|    |         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:9.4.0 -> 11.0.1 (*)
|    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.4.0 -> 11.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.adobe.creativesdk.android.shared.common:common-ui:1.1.8
|    |    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1 -> 25.2.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.1.1 -> 25.0.0 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:palette-v7:25.0.0
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.0.0 -> 25.2.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:25.0.0 -> 25.2.0 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:design:25.0.0
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:25.0.0 -> 25.2.0 (*)
|    |    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0 -> 25.2.0 (*)
|    |    +--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.0.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.android.support:transition:25.0.0
|    |         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:25.0.0 -> 25.2.0 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.0.0 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.0.0
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.0.0 -> 25.2.0
|    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0 -> 25.2.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:9.4.0 -> 11.0.1 (*)
|    +--- it.sephiroth.android.library.imagezoom:imagezoom:2.2.5
|    +--- it.sephiroth.android.library.ab:ab-test:2.0.5
|    +--- org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0
|    +--- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4
|    +--- io.reactivex:rxjava:1.2.2
|    +--- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1 -> 3.6.0 (*)
|    +--- com.infstory:proguard-annotations:1.0.2
|    +--- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.4.1
|    |    \--- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1 -> 3.6.0 (*)
|    \--- com.localytics.android:library:4.0.1
\--- com.localytics.android:library:3.8.0 -> 4.0.1
```

Comment: run `gradlew app:dependencies` and post output. section releaseCompileClasspath is important

Comment: Use play Service Version `11.0.1` for google will solve your problem. https://stackoverflow.com/a/44541963/7806873

Comment: @NitinPatel 11.0.1 not working , same problem occurred, while generate apk.

Comment: @DeKaNszn I mentioned releaseCompile section in question , as per your suggestion , check now please.

Comment: @UmeshDevani added answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got solution, in build.gradle i changed library to 10.2.0

```
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite:10.2.0'
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:10.2.0'
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.2.0'
```

From Main Project gradle i removed :

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

Change following libraries versions:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.0.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.0.2' 
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.2'
```

If didn't work, try with versions 11.0.3 and 11.0.4

Comment: Why? The issue will be the same and in this way you are going to add more not used module.

Comment: i tried with all version 11.0.1, 11.0.2, 11.0.3 and 11.0.4 , but facing same issue. @R.R.M

Comment: Ok then try to remove 'jumboMode true' from dexOptions

Comment: Same issue after remove jumboMode  @R.R.M

Comment: @R.R.M Error occured after implementing below in gradle       `compile 'com.adobe.creativesdk.foundation:auth:0.9.1251'
    compile 'com.adobe.creativesdk:image:4.8.4'
    compile 'com.localytics.android:library:3.8.0'`

Comment: Ok try to refer this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42374151/all-com-android-support-libraries-must-use-the-exact-same-version-specification/42589182

Answer (score 0):

In your dependencies, instead of

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
```

try with

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
```

Ignore the warning that says you shouldn't use "+" as versions.

Comment: Don't use `+` in gradle dependencies

Comment: @DeKaNszn Android Studio initializes many of its dependencies with "+"

Comment: Default templates for gradle files does not provide `+` in versions

Comment: the reason you don't is that you might build one day and your library has changed and you might not realise that you've broken something - in the context of "oh god I can't even create a project" it's okay to use ```+``` to let gradle select the version it wants, that could expose the real issue or at least be exactly as broken as it already was

Answer (score 0):

You should force `com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.0.1` in your dependencies

Watch in your dependencies output: `com.adobe.creativesdk:image` wants Google Play Services library version 9.4.0, which wants some internal dependencies with version 9.4.0. But `com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.0.0` wants internal dependencies version 11.0.0. Most simplest solution - force new version.

```
+--- com.adobe.creativesdk:image:4.8.4
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.4.0 // conflict here
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:9.4.0 -> 11.0.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.4.0 -> 11.0.1 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-iid:9.4.0 // conflict here
|    |         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:9.4.0 -> 11.0.1 (*)
|    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.4.0 -> 11.0.1 (*)
```

Comment: That cause additional error of rxjava.properties and .rxjava.jar , i posted final answer

Comment: @UmeshDevani rxjava.properties fixed by Google in 11.0.1