# Why do I get Program type already present: com.google.common.base.FinalizableReference

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-3.0

I am migrating my project from Android Studio 2.3.3 to 3.1.3. When compiling my project I get the following error message:

```
Program type already present: com.google.common.base.FinalizableReference
Message{kind=ERROR, text=Program type already present: com.google.common.base.FinalizableReference, sources=[Unknown source file], tool name=Optional.of(D8)}
```

Is it relevant to my dependencies?

```
dependencies {
 implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
 implementation project(':app-lib')
 implementation 'cn.jiguang.sdk:jcore:1.1.2'
 implementation 'cn.jiguang.sdk:jpush:3.0.5'
 implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
 implementation 'com.andrognito.patternlockview:patternlockview:1.0.0'
 implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.0.0'
 implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
 implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.0"
 implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:20.0'
 implementation 'com.navercorp.pulltorefresh:library:3.2.0@aar'
 implementation 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:2.2.0'
 implementation 'net.danlew:android.joda:2.9.4'
 implementation 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.4.1'
 annotationProcessor 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.4.1'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in play services 11.0.0 version. Use 11.0.1. That should fix the problem.

Found the answer in this stackoverflow link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44541963/10243401